# SAS: column position rearrangement

Tags: sas

I would like to rearange variable column poistion depending on ft value: for example. if ft =1, then put o2 and o5 @33 and 34. if ft=2, then put o2 and o5 @35 and 36 and so on... But I think I got the loop and array incorrect below. Can someone point out what I did wrong?

```
data fttry1;
 input ft m1 o2 m3 m4 o5;
 datalines;
 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 2 7 8 9 10 11
 3 12 13 14 15 20
 4 16 17 18 19 21
 ;
run;

data fttry2;
 set fttry1;
 file print notitles;
 put   @10 ft
       @30 M1
       @31 M3-M4;
 do ft =1 to 4;
  array ftposition[2] o2 o5;
  do i=1 to 2;
   do l=33 to 34 by 2;
    put @l ftposition[i];
   end;
  end;
 end;
run;
```

Comment: It is unclear how you would deal with 2-digit number.Like what you have coded here, for the third and fourth row, m1,m3 and m4 are all 2-digit number, which will cause position overlapping in output.

Comment: I did not think about that issue. But the main problem with the above is that o2 and o5 do not stay on the same line as other variables. Maybe this is related to what you mentoined. I don't know. I can try to fix their digit after put statement like 2.

Comment: If the whole data set you would like to process is as simple as the example here (only 2 variables needs location adjust), the solution could be very easy.

Comment: what if I only have one digit values in each variable? I think I just don't get the loop function right. But the two variables' locations need to be fixed in condition to ft value. do you have any opinion about how to fix this in case all the values are one digit?

Comment: see my answer. maybe not very useful in complicated case though.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
data fttry1;
 input ft m1 o2 m3 m4 o5;
 datalines;
 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 2 7 8 9 10 11
 3 12 13 14 15 20
 4 16 17 18 19 21
 ;
run;

data fttry2;
 set fttry1;
 file print notitles;
 cnt + 1;
 put   @10 ft
       @30 M1
       @31 M3-M4 @;
  o2_loc=(ft+cnt) + 32;
  o5_loc=(ft+cnt) + 33;
 put @o2_loc o2 @;
 put @o5_loc o5 ;
run;
```

**EDIT**
[This](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002051739.htm) link indicates that a trailing @ sign will prevent a newline after a PUT statement.

Comment: doesn't seem to behave o2 and o5. they are not on the same line as m1-m4.

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the comment, 2-digit number is problematic. So I don't include m3, m4 for output. Use "ft" as a pointer since it is like a serial number (is it?). Get length of o2 to ensure there is no overlapping between o2 and o5.

```
data fttry1;
 input ft m1 o2 m3 m4 o5;
 datalines;
 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 2 7 8 9 10 11
 3 12 13 14 15 20
 4 16 17 18 19 21
 ;
run;

data fttry2;
 set fttry1;
 file print notitles;
 by ft;
    put @10 ft
        @30 M1
        @(31+2*ft) o2
        @(31+2*ft+length(cats(o2))) o5;
run;
```

Comment: brilliant Robbie! thank you for such a good solution and insight to look at this in a different way!

Comment: the "i" loop (2 instances) will create 2 rows corresponding to every 1 row in the original data set. btw, choose the answer you accept.